# php redirect to last page requested after login

Tags: php

I need help regarding my login system. In my project when a user logs in they simply go to their account. If they are browsing some pages and asked to login then they should redirect to that page after login and not their profile page.

I want to some authenticate user only see some page otherwise redirect to referrer page and send the message "You can't access this page." and also checked the user is logged in or not.
If user is not logged in then forced to logging in.

here is my code:-
access_page.php file which is only access by user level 1.

```
<?php
include "auth_user.php";
?>


<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>
 This is access page...

</body>
</html>
```

auth_user.php file where check user is authenticate  or not

```
<?php
    include("sql.php");
    session_start();

    function Destroy() {
        unset($_SESSION['UID']);
        unset($_SESSION['USERNAME']);
        unset($_SESSION['user_level']);
        header("location: user_login.php");
    }

    if(isset($_SESSION['UID']) && isset($_SESSION['USERNAME'])) {
        $UID = $_SESSION['UID'];
        $username = $_SESSION['USERNAME'];
        $qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `UID` = '$UID' AND `Username` = '$username'");


        if(mysql_num_rows($qry) == 1) 
        {
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qry))
            {
                 $_SESSION['user_level']=$row['user_level'];
                 if($_SESSION['user_level']==1)
                 {
                      header("location:access_page.php");
                 }
                 else
                 {
                        header("location:".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."");
                      echo "you can't view these access page "; 
                 }
            }
        }
        else
        {
         Destroy(); 
        };
    } else { Destroy(); }
?>
```

Here check user is authenticate or not.
If it is true then then user redirect to access_page.php but here the output is page is not redirecting properly. Please giude me how to redirect the page and redirect to last page requested after login.

Thank you..

Comment: Usually websites do something like `login?redirect=http://url-of-last-page`

Comment: Thank you, but i can't able to access the authenticate page which is access_page.php. how can i redirect it

Answer (score 0):

simply, you could set a condition to your last page if it was come from your login link then redirect to user profile else or on login request redirect to the last page.